# iOS Box API - wait for request to finish

Tags: objective-c, box-api

Is there a way to wait for the Box API to finish all requests? So for example, if I make a folder item request, I would like to have my program wait for the completion handler to finish before moving on.

As an example:

```
BOXContentClient *contentClient = [BOXContentClient defaultClient];

BOXFolderItemsRequest *listAllInRoot = [contentClient folderItemsRequestWithID:BOXAPIFolderIDRoot];

[listAllInRoot performRequestWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSError *error) {
    //Do something with the results here
}

// Wait here for the completion handler to finish before moving on
```

I had a go at using an NSCondition, however I am wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Use a dispatch_group and Dispatch_group_wait

Comment: @Paulw11 - Ok, so I've tried this and weirdly, it does not seem to work. I never see "Here1" or "Here2".

``BOXFolderItemsRequest *listAllInRoot = [contentClient folderItemsRequestWithID:BOXAPIFolderIDRoot];
    
    dispatch_group_t boxGroup = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(boxGroup);
    [listAllInRoot performRequestWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSError *error) {
        std::cout << "Here1\n";
        dispatch_group_leave(boxGroup);
    }];
    
    dispatch_group_wait(boxGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    std::cout << "Here2\n";``

Comment: Don't use std::cout. Use `NSLog`

Answer (score 2):

(Swift 5.x) You can use this code :

```
var a: [String:Any]

func myFunction(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> () ) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // For example your action on a
    }
}


myFunction { (status) in
    if status {
        print(a!)
    }
}
```